# How to figure out the number of connection opened simultaneously by an host over time with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to find out how many connections are open with respect to one IP over time ? Meaning at time t1, t2, t3 and so on, if it is not per host, overall is fine. I'm testing my producer, and trying to figure out how it is tapping onto the service behind nginx.

is there some variables in nginx to figure that out ?

Answer (score 0):

Import access log files into your time series database of choice. Query the source of interest and graph it over time.

More basic stats can found by querying the web servers status APIs. On Linux, a quick way to do this is to [install netdata on a web server](https://github.com/netdata/netdata/wiki/The-spectacles-of-a-web-server-log-file). It is not a per IP query, but you can get a graph of current connections easily.

NGINX has a rate limiting feature if you want to set limits.